# Tailwind Browserslist not working in macos bigsur safari browser version 14.1

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, responsive, tailwind-css

I have landing page issue when opening in Safari BigSur browser version 14.1

there are some classes from tailwind that don't work

I've added autoprefixer and browserslist but still no change

```
"name": "01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "browserslist": [
    "Chrome > 61",
    "Edge > 16",
    "Firefox > 60",
    "Safari > 10.1"
  ],
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "browserslist": "^4.20.4",
    "i18next": "^21.8.3",
    "swiper": "^8.1.4"
  }
```

is there any other way so tailwind can support in all browsers?

Comment: Do you have an example or screenshot of the HTML that's causing problems? What are you expecting to happen on safari but is not working?

Comment: are you using a macbook?

if yes, try opening this website
alxsteven24.github.io/burnerindo

the web when opened in chrome, opera and ie no problem

but when i open it on mac safari, the section before the footer crashes